# Refactoring into Java 8 stream

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, java-stream

i have method that viewed under message.
I want refactored this method from "for each" to stream view
like myCollect.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(..)))
but don't understand how it does work Collectors.toMap(..).

```
private <T extends Entity> Map<String, Object> prepareEntity(T entity) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> preparedEntity = new LinkedHashMap<>(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
        Objects.requireNonNull(entity);
        Class clazz = entity.getClass();

        List<Field> openFields = getDeclaredFields(clazz, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);

        for (Field field : openFields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            preparedEntity.put(field.getName(), field.getType().equals(Boolean.class)
                    ? ("true".equals(field.get(entity).toString())) ? 1 : 0
                    : field.get(entity));
        }

        return preparedEntity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
return openFields.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::getName,
                                           field->field.getType().equals(Boolean.class)? 
                                                  ("true".equals(field.get(entity).toString())) ? 1 : 0
                                                  : field.get(entity)
                                           )
                         );
```

Comment: IDEA show error message "Cannot resolve method 'getName'"   I was try to did like this, too

Comment: @BabyGluk Is it `java.lang.reflect.Field`? That class has a `Field::getField` method, so it should work. You can try to replace the method reference with a lambda expression : `field -> field.getName()`.

Comment: If it is `java.lang.reflect.Field`, I would use `field.getBoolean(entity)? 1: 0` rather than this strange `("true".equals(field.get(entity).toString())) ? 1 : 0`…